# NullPointerException on "list.clear()"

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

What I'm doing is working with a text document that I'm pulling numbers from a saved text document, each line has its own number, and it ignores any lines starting with a !, so, when using these codes, I am getting a NullPointerException and I'm not sure why, Its not filling the ArrayList because of this, how come?

```
try{

               File f = new File(extStorageDirectory+"/data.txt");

               FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);

               BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));

               String readString = new String();

               integers.clear();
               char check;
               while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){
                   check = readString.charAt(0);
                  if(check == '!'){

                  }
                  else{
                      //integers.add(0,Integer.parseInt(readString));
                      if(check == 0){
                          integers.add(0);
                      } else {
                          if(check == 1) {
                              integers.add(1);
                          } else {
                              if(check == 2){
                                  integers.add(2);
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
               }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Find Data: "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: What line are you getting it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a stacktrace indicating what line number the `NullPointerException` occurs on, we can only guess. Looking at the posted code, I don't see `integers` being initialized anywhere. So `integers.clear()` could potentially be throwing a `NullPointerException`. Perhaps you're missing a line like:

```
integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Put is somewhere where it executes prior to the call to `integers.clear();`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm going to admit I forgot to check the stacktrace, But yes, you can assume everything has been initialized and working through the entire application, let me check

Comment: It was initialized, but in the wrong order, I accidentally initialized it after i called the method, thanks for putting me in the right direction, rookie mistake

Comment: No problem. Sometimes you just need a 2nd pair of eyes on the code. :)

Comment: `But yes, you can assume everything has been initialized and working through the entire application` That's a horrible assumption when you get a null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

In your current code snippet

integers

is never initialized...